# In Groovy, String.split(regex, int) does not produce the expected results

Tags: string, groovy, split

I'm trying to split a String and retain `n + 1` items where there are `n` delimiters.  There are many solutions here on SO that suggest using `.split(regex, -1)` to retrieve all tokens.  This is not working, however, when trying it in Groovy.

```
println ",,,,,,".split(",", -1).length
```

prints 0

Any idea what I can do about this to get consistent behavior with the Java method? Calling `.toString()` on it makes no difference (Converting `GString` to `java.lang.String`)

edit:  I also had `String.mixin StringUtils` in my script.  There is no conflicting method signature since `StringUtils` does not have a `.split(regex, int)` method defined.  Am I using mixin incorrectly? Is there any way to have this play nicely together?

edit2:
[image]

Comment: If i drop the -1 parameter, it prints 0. What do you expect it to print?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I had `String.mixin org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils` in my script.  That's very strange though that it would override such simple behavior.

Comment: Removed the Java tag, as this is to do with calling original methods when you've overwritten them with a mixin in groovy, no?

Comment: @tim_yates, that's fine to remove java, but am I actually overriding anything? There is no conflicting method signature with `java.lang.String.split(String regex, int length)` and `StringUtils`.  I'm calling split with 2 parameters, not 3, so the method you linked shouldn't be called, right?

Comment: Yes, Groovy is behaving as expected. If you have nothing between your delimiter, it returns length 0. If you place character between the delimiter, like "x,x,x,x,x,x,x the length will be correct (7) in this case. You can even drop the last 'x' and leave the delimiter: "x,x,x,x,x,x," and it will correctly return (6).

Comment: Doesn't mixing stringutils in mean you're [calling this method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int))? The first parameter is the string itself

Comment: Potentially, but I didn't think I was calling it in a static way.  I'm calling it on an instance of `String`, instead of `StringUtils.split(...)`  I need to do some more testing on this myself since it's kind of a new problem from what I originally suspected.  Thank you both for your input.

Comment: I might be wrong, my accuracy goes down on Saturday nights, and I've not currently got access to my laptop... I'll check tomorrow if you have no luck, and no one else jumps in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are definitely being affected by mixing in the `StringUtils` class. If you run this:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
String str = ",,,,,,"

println "String..."
println str.split(",",-1).length
println str.split(",").length
def methods = String.metaClass.methods*.name.sort().unique()
println "$methods.size:$methods"

println "\nStringUtils..."
println StringUtils.split(str, ",").length
println StringUtils.split(str,",",-1).length

println "\nStringUtils mixin..."
String.mixin StringUtils
println str.split(",",-1).length
println str.split(",").length
methods = String.metaClass.methods*.name.sort().unique()
println "$methods.size:$methods"
```

You will get the output:

```
String...
7
0
43:[charAt, codePointAt, codePointBefore, codePointCount, compareTo, compareToIgnoreCase, concat, contains, contentEquals, copyValueOf, endsWith, equals, equalsIgnoreCase, format, getBytes, getChars, getClass, hashCode, indexOf, intern, isEmpty, join, lastIndexOf, length, matches, notify, notifyAll, offsetByCodePoints, regionMatches, replace, replaceAll, replaceFirst, split, startsWith, subSequence, substring, toCharArray, toLowerCase, toString, toUpperCase, trim, valueOf, wait]

StringUtils...
0
0

StringUtils mixin...
0
0
149:[abbreviate, abbreviateMiddle, appendIfMissing, appendIfMissingIgnoreCase, capitalize, center, charAt, chomp, chop, codePointAt, codePointBefore, codePointCount, compareTo, compareToIgnoreCase, concat, contains, containsAny, containsIgnoreCase, containsNone, containsOnly, containsWhitespace, contentEquals, copyValueOf, countMatches, defaultIfBlank, defaultIfEmpty, defaultString, deleteWhitespace, difference, endsWith, endsWithAny, endsWithIgnoreCase, equals, equalsIgnoreCase, format, getBytes, getCR, getChars, getClass, getEMPTY, getFuzzyDistance, getINDEX_NOT_FOUND, getJaroWinklerDistance, getLF, getLevenshteinDistance, getPAD_LIMIT, getSPACE, hashCode, indexOf, indexOfAny, indexOfAnyBut, indexOfDifference, indexOfIgnoreCase, intern, isAllLowerCase, isAllUpperCase, isAlpha, isAlphaSpace, isAlphanumeric, isAlphanumericSpace, isAsciiPrintable, isBlank, isEmpty, isNotBlank, isNotEmpty, isNumeric, isNumericSpace, isWhitespace, join, lastIndexOf, lastIndexOfAny, lastIndexOfIgnoreCase, lastOrdinalIndexOf, left, leftPad, length, lowerCase, matches, mid, normalizeSpace, notify, notifyAll, offsetByCodePoints, ordinalIndexOf, overlay, prependIfMissing, prependIfMissingIgnoreCase, regionMatches, remove, removeEnd, removeEndIgnoreCase, removePattern, removeStart, removeStartIgnoreCase, repeat, replace, replaceAll, replaceChars, replaceEach, replaceEachRepeatedly, replaceFirst, replaceOnce, replacePattern, reverse, reverseDelimited, right, rightPad, setCR, setEMPTY, setINDEX_NOT_FOUND, setLF, setPAD_LIMIT, setSPACE, split, splitByCharacterType, splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase, splitByWholeSeparator, splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens, splitPreserveAllTokens, startsWith, startsWithAny, startsWithIgnoreCase, strip, stripAccents, stripEnd, stripStart, stripToEmpty, stripToNull, subSequence, substring, substringAfter, substringAfterLast, substringBefore, substringBeforeLast, substringBetween, substringsBetween, swapCase, toCharArray, toLowerCase, toString, toUpperCase, trim, trimToEmpty, trimToNull, uncapitalize, upperCase, valueOf, wait, wrap]
```

Showing that the behavior is different without the `mixin StringUtils`.
In fact, plain ol' Groovy is returning 7 if you add the -1 and 0 without, which is a result of using the common Java `split()` method, and both Java, Groovy return the same result.

`StringUtils` retuns 0 with or without the -1 parameter.

In addition, you can see that the `String` class has 43 methods before applying the mixin, which then shows `String` to have 149 methods, where the additional methods match those found in `StringUtils`

So, you will notice that the 2 lines after the `println "\StringUtils..."` statement output the same result as when executed with the mixed in `StringUtils`, both statements returning 0.

When doing a mixin, it is similar to currying, in that the original String 'str' is passed to the `StringUtils.split()` method as the first argument. For this reason, the 2 statements when using the mixin that have 2 arguments and 1 respectively, are equivalent to the 2 statements using `StringUtils` without the mixin, having 3 and 2 arguments.

More specifically:

```
str.split(",",-1) == StringUtils.split(str, ",", -1)
```

once you apply the mixin

Comment: I'm getting the output of `7 0`, not `0 7`, when running your script.  (using org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils)

Comment: I updated the answer to show both with/without the -1 parameter.

Comment: Thank you for all of the additional details, this has been very helpful in understanding where my error was.  I did not know that the original instance was passed to the mixin method, which is why I didn't think there was a conflict in the method signatures.  Great post :)